# Using javascript regex to retrieve year from date string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have to retrieve the year from date string. the date string format should be any of the following formats. I need to globalized code to retrieve the year in any date string formats.

Date formats, "30/8/2013","08/30/2013",30-8-2013","2013-08-30","30.8.2013","30-08-13","13-08-30" etc.

Comment: This is code,var reg = /(yyyy)|(yy)/;
var formattedDt = "30/08/2013"; //"30-08-2013","30.08.2013","08.30.13" etc.,
var minYear = "";
formattedDt = formattedDt.replace(reg, minYear);
alert(minYear);

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/object-property-method/date-getFullYear.php

Comment: how would you differentiate if date comes as 13-09-13? do you also have format stored somewhere like yy-mm-dd?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library. http://momentjs.com/

This is probably your best option available.

Comment: You can parse date string of any format using moment.js. Once you parse it, getting a year is trivial like this m.year();

Answer (score 0):

01-02-03 could be 2001-02-03 or 01-02-2003, it is impossible to make sure if you don't have other restriction.

For "30/8/2013","08/30/2013",30-8-2013","2013-08-30","30.8.2013", you can use this regex:

```
var pat = /(\d{4})[\-\/\.]\d+[\-\/\.]\d+|\d+[\-\/\.]\d+[\-\/\.](\d{4})/;
r = "30/8/2013".match(pat); console.log(r);
r = "08/30/2013".match(pat); console.log(r);
r = "30-8-2013".match(pat); console.log(r);
r = "2013-08-30".match(pat); console.log(r);
r = "30.8.2013".match(pat); console.log(r);
r = "30-08-13".match(pat); console.log(r);
r = "13-08-30".match(pat); console.log(r);
```

which outputs:

```
["30/8/2013", undefined, "2013", index: 0, input: "30/8/2013"] test.js:2
["08/30/2013", undefined, "2013", index: 0, input: "08/30/2013"] test.js:3
["30-8-2013", undefined, "2013", index: 0, input: "30-8-2013"] test.js:4
["2013-08-30", "2013", undefined, index: 0, input: "2013-08-30"] test.js:5
["30.8.2013", undefined, "2013", index: 0, input: "30.8.2013"] test.js:6
null test.js:7
null test.js:8
```

Comment: thanks, it is displayed the 2013/8/30,2013,. I want only the year value. help me.

Comment: Please check it. the 30-08-13 case it is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/45PNy/1/

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var myDate="30.08.2013";

if(myDate.indexOf(".")!= -1){
    var spliter=".";
}else if(myDate.indexOf("/")!= -1){
    var spliter="/";
}
else if(myDate.indexOf("-")!= -1){
    var spliter="-";
}
var year="";
var myDateAray= myDate.split(spliter);
for( i=0;i<myDateAray.length;i++){
    if(myDateAray[i].length > 2){

         year=myDateAray[i];
        break;
    }

    }
alert(year);
```